# UnboundLocalError in ggplot 0.5

Tags: python, pandas, python-ggplot

I have the following code

```
p = ggplot(aes(x='DHT temp',y='temp3'), data=data)
p + geom_point(alpha=0.1, size=10) + scale_x_continuous(limits=(20,30)) + 
scale_y_continuous(limits=(0,170)) + theme_bw()\
+ geom_abline(intercept=20)
```

and I get the following error:

```
<repr(<ggplot.ggplot.ggplot at 0x607a3d0>) 
failed: UnboundLocalError: local variable 'x' referenced before assignment>
```

some sample data

```
     HIH     DHThum  DHTtemp temp1   temp3
0    350     67.7    22.7    328     148
1    356     67.9    22.7    328     149
2    365     67.8    22.7    328     148
3    349     67.9    22.6    327     148
4    348     68.0    22.6    328     149
```

Comment: Hm. Can you try:

```
import ggplot
print ggplot.__version__
```

And perhaps pasting a few rows of your data would also help reproduce the issue you're seeing too.

Comment: It's done above . thanks

Comment: there's a space in your x variable name in `aes` but not in your data frame? 'DHT temp' vs 'DHTtemp'. Is that it?

Comment: I am using `x`and `y`as axis indicators.

Comment: Can you please store the final ggplot object (`p = p + ...`) and run `p.draw()` on it. This should result in a complete stacktrace insteed of only the error message. I think this is a bug in gpplots code, so opening an issue at https://github.com/yhat/ggplot would be nice. :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This was a [bug in ggplot](https://github.com/yhat/ggplot/issues/332) which has been fixed in version 0.5.8.

Answer (score 1):

Great. Thx for posting some data. Unfortunately, I'm not able to recreate the issue on my end.

```
from ggplot import *
import pandas as pd
import re

data = """
     HIH     DHThum  DHTtemp temp1   temp3
0    350     67.7    22.7    328     148
1    356     67.9    22.7    328     149
2    365     67.8    22.7    328     148
3    349     67.9    22.6    327     148
4    348     68.0    22.6    328     149
"""

data = [re.split('\s+', line) for line in data.split('\n') if line]

headers, data = data[0], data[1:]
headers[0] = 'index_col'

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=headers)
df = df.astype(float)

p = ggplot(aes('DHTtemp', 'temp3'), data=df)

p = p + geom_point(alpha=0.1, size=10) + \
    scale_x_continuous(limits=(20,30)) + \
    scale_y_continuous(limits=(0,170)) + theme_bw() + \
    geom_abline(intercept=20)

ggsave('plot.png', p)
```

The plot renders for me without the exception you're seeing. Of course, since this is only the top 5 rows, the plot doesn't really describe anything interesting.

[image]

Will keep digging and ask a few people on my team if they know what's up.